# Color all the remaining rows after certain condition is met in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

How to color all the remaining rows after certain condition is met in a cell in  a GridView

Grid with template column

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grdHeader" ItemStyle-Width="22%">
                                         <ItemTemplate>
                                             <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" ><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status_Id")%></asp:Label>
                                         </ItemTemplate> 
                                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

For example,If a grid has 10 rows,  if the Status_Id = 1 in a 4th row ,I need to color all the remaining 6 rows.

Using RowDataBound Event how to achieve this

```
void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {

    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the status id for the current row in RowDataBound. If it matches what you're looking for, set a value in a hidden field or global variable or something. Also in RowDataBound, check whether that value has already been set. If it has, then you know you are past the row where you found the status id, so now change the row color for this row.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<foo> lst = GetList();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append(@"
<div class='grdHeader'>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Status ID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
");

bool colorTheRest = false;

foreach (var foo in lst)
{
    if (colorTheRest)
    {
        sb.Append("<tr class='trColor'>");
    }
    else
    {
        sb.Append("<tr class='trNoColor'>");
    }

    if (foo.status == 1)
    {
        colorTheRest = true;
    }

    sb.Append($@"
<td>{foo.status}</td>
<td>{foo.name}</td>
<td>{foo.amount}</td>
</tr>
");
}

sb.Append("</table></div>");
```

Add a placeholder at the ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Continue at the code behind:

```
ph1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
```

Then, you can color it in CSS style block:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .grdHeader th {
        /*your-style here*/
    }
    .trColor {
        background: gray;
    }
    .trNoColor {
        background: white;
    }
</style>
```